# Using a php function inside a php echo

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to setup my WordPress website so that if a post / page has a featured image assigned, this image will be used as the page banner. If however the page doesn't have a featured image, it must onload select a random image out of six available options. I've tried to used this if statement below:

```
<div id="slider">
    <div class="theslide">
        <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            the_post_thumbnail();
        }
        else {
            echo '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/link-ship-chandlers-banner-' . $random = rand(1,6); '.jpg">';
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works, but the random number function is not closing preperly, so the code ends up looking like this:

```
<div id="slider">
<div class="theslide">
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/link-ship-chandlers-banner-6  &lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
```

Instead of like this:

```
<div id="slider">
<div class="theslide">
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/link-ship-chandlers-banner-6.jpg">
</div>
</div>
```

I'm assuming my syntax is wrong for using php inside of the echo, but everything I try either has the same problem or cause a php error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Willem

Comment: As Mikk3lRo pointed out is his code only post. You should just use the `rand(1,6)`. Also don't use semi-colon before the end of the echo. If you need the value of `$random` later in your code then assign it prior to the echo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need to know which header was chosen, just do this:

```
echo '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/link-ship-chandlers-banner-' . rand(1,6) . '.jpg">';
```

Using more than one `;` on a line is a no-go (you are essentially telling the php-interpreter that `'.jpg">';` is an independant command - which will do nothing)

Assigning a variable (ie. `$whatever = 'something`) inside the `echo` statement won't be a problem in this case - though it really doesn't do any good either. What it does is create a new variable called `$random` that you could use afterwards to find out which header was used - but results will be unpredictable if used in the `echo` statement (ie. in your case the variable would contain `[random number].jpg`, not just the random number), instead assign the random number to `$random` first like this:

```
$random = rand(1,6);
echo '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/link-ship-chandlers-banner-' . $random . '.jpg">';
echo "We are using header {$random}, which was chosen at random.";
```

Note that the above example also shows an alternate way to include the variable in a string - using double-quotes you can simply write the variable directly inside the string itself. When doing so I recommend always using `{}` to wrap the variable though not needed in this case - this allows referencing more complex variables (such as array elements or object properties), and it makes the whole thing more readable too.

Other (IMO less readable, possibly more error-prone) solutions include:

```
$random = rand(1,6);
echo "<img src=\"/wp-content/uploads/link-ship-chandlers-banner-$random.jpg\">";
echo sprintf('<img src="/wp-content/uploads/link-ship-chandlers-banner-%d.jpg">', $random);
printf('<img src="/wp-content/uploads/link-ship-chandlers-banner-%d.jpg">', $random);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually this can work, but you end the line with `;`.
So removing the `;` and adding a `.`

```
echo '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/link-ship-chandlers-banner-' . $random = rand(1,6) . '.jpg">';
```

do this alternatively you don't need to set this variable

```
echo '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/link-ship-chandlers-banner-' . rand(1,6) . '.jpg">';
```

Comment: True it'll work. But I recommend setting the variable prior to the `echo` to make to code that tiny bit more readable. Or just skip assigning at all if it's not used again later.

Comment: @VuoriLiikaluoma i just said, it will work, not that this is good code (:

Comment: I know, I was just confirming that it does work and recommending otherwise for other readers. :)